# Trying to use interp1d

Tags: python

I am fairly new to python and have started with 2.7 as that is what is used at work. I am trying to learn about interpolating. It is not going well. I am trying to import a list consisting of between 1000 and 6500 entries. That is easy enough.The hard part comes in when I'm trying to figure out how to insert 9 spaces between every item in the list and then interpolate the 9 steps between.

I want to end with a new text file being written.  I can open, read, and write a new file. The stuff I need to do in the middle is looking out of reach. Everything I read about has a second array and I don't understand how I should configure one for my task, or if I need it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. FYI, the list of numbers being read in have 3 decimal places.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You are much more likely to receive an answer if your question includes an example of your input, your expected output, what you have tried to get that output and your actual output as well as any errors you received.

Answer (score 0):

This would solve your problem for evenly spaced data. Consider posting some of your own code in the future so that answers can be tailored to your exact difficulty.

```
from scipy import interpolate
import numpy as np

def interp_function(sx, sy, tau = 10):

    sy_fnc = interpolate.splrep(sx, sy, s=0)   
    tau_interp = float(sx.max() - sx.min()) / float(tau * len(sx))
    sx_interp = np.arange(sx[0], sx[len(sx)-1], tau_interp)    
    sy_interp = interpolate.splev(sx_interp, sy_fnc, der=0)
    return sx_interp, sy_interp
```